# How to pull just first numbers out of data in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have data that I just need to pull an order number out of. Below is an example of the data.

`Mouse, Mickey #12340 Bilateral L5-S1 Transforaminal Epidural Steroid Injection`

I just want to pull the `#12340` out. How can I do this?

I tried this

```
select 
SUBSTRING(columnname, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', columnname), LEN(columnname))
```

and got rid of everything before the 1 but need to get rid of everything after the last number as well.

Comment: Presumably this is SQL Server. Can you reliably know that there's a trailing space after the order number or that the order number is 5-6 digits? Is it better to search for the pound character or just look for the first digit character? Variations is where this stuff gets trickier.

Comment: `rtrim(substring(col, charindex('#', col) + 1, 6))`??

Comment: Is there any particular reason a host of unrelated data is stored under the same string column, as opposed to separate columns allowing you to `SELECT ... FROM table WHERE order_number = 12340`?

Comment: I would suggest to rearrange your database structure, if possible. Order number, together with the name and some other information in 1 string, so presumabely in 1 field, sounds spooky to me. Add fields for order, name, surname, treatment, ...

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34661595) to provide *several* sample records so we can see any possible variations?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are extracting the substring starting from the first occurrence of number until the end of the string, maybe subtracting position of # and first non number character after # from total length of columnname might help:

```
select SUBSTRING(columnname, PATINDEX('%#%', columnname), LEN(columnname) - 
PATINDEX('%#%', columnname) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(columnname, 
PATINDEX('%#%', columnname), LEN(columnname))))
```